# How to apply a shadow to a UITextView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I tried applying a shadow to my `UITextView` as I did for my `UIView` but it's not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code :

### Obj-C

```
txtView.layer.cornerRadius = txtView.frame.size.height/2;
txtView.clipsToBounds = NO;
txtView.layer.shadowOpacity=0.4;
txtView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3);
```

### Swift

```
txtView.layer.cornerRadius = txtView.frame.size.height/2
txtView.clipsToBounds = false
txtView.layer.shadowOpacity=0.4
txtView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 3)
```

I hope it's work for you.

Comment: Swift 5:-


speechTextView.layer.cornerRadius = speechTextView.frame.size.height/2

speechTextView.clipsToBounds = false

speechTextView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4

speechTextView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)


Note:- CGSizeMake is not available in Swift 3